# EmEditorでマクロを動作させたときのファイルのみにしか動作しない設定は可能でしょうか？

Tags: emeditor

初期設定ではマクロを動作中にファイルを開くと開いたファイルでもマクロが継続して動作します。
間違って何か関連付けた別のテキストファイルなどをクリックするとマクロが別に開いた方のファイルで稼働を続行してグチャグチャになります。
もし上書き保存設定をしてるとファイルが破損することになります。現在は上書きしていないので、破損はないですが、実行したときの対象ファイルでしかマグロが動作しないように設定できますでしょうか？

別にEmEditorでファイルを開いた場合は、影響せずに閲覧できてバックグラウンドで、実行したときのファイルのみマクロも続行するという仕組みです。

それとマクロを途中でキャンセルできますでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ご質問の意味がはっきりしないのですが、`doc1 = document;` などとして、`doc1` を対象としてマクロを記述すれば、ご希望の動作になると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。説明不足でした。
初期設定ではマクロを動作中にファイルを開くと「マクロが動作中に途中で」開いたファイルでも「マクロが移行して」継続して動作します。
という現象です。

質問させていただきましたときには認識できてませんでしたが、動作テストしてみたところ、私の書きました現象は、いくつかの条件が重ならないと起きない問題のようです。

通常作っている普通のマクロ、EmEditorでほとんどの人がやるマクロでは、動作中に切り替えても、この問題は発生しませんでしたので、その現象が起きている人自体がまれかと思います。

現象を再現できるマクロをメールさせて頂きます。doc1 = document;をつけても同様でした。最新バージョンでも起きました。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: キャンセルできますかという質問については、マクロの造り方次第で変わりました。教えて頂きましたbatch_list = editor.filters;の造り方だと普通にキャンセルボタンが出ますが、それ以外のマクロはキャンセルボタンがない場合が多いので、EmEditorじたいで強制キャンセルできる停止ボタンを作って頂きたいです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: この質問はEmEditorに対する誤解を招く可能性がありますので、数日後に削除致します。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: お世話になっております。違う話題にはなりますが、連続クリップボード機能の要望はいかがでしたでしょうか？EmEditorを使う人とのニーズはぴったしと思います。

Comment: 連続クリップボード機能とはどういう意味でしょうか?

Comment: ありがとうございます。2月20日に「以下の機能を追加していただけませんでしょうか？」というタイトルで送らせて頂いたメールの要望です。この機能は、他のソフトウェアでもなかなかないので、付いていると希少価値が高いです。